# Aggregation solution Django

Tags: python, django, aggregation

I am trying to get the total for sold products, here is the code:

models.py

```
class Ventas(models.Model):
  codigoventa = models.CharField(max_length=7, unique=True)
  codigocliente = models.ForeignKey('Clientes')
  Fecha_registro = models.DateTimeField("Fecha de edicion", auto_now_add=True) 
  totalventa = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places = 2)
  codigosucursal = models.ForeignKey('Sucursales')
  totalventa = models.IntegerField()

  def __unicode__(self):
      return self.codigoventa
```

Views.py

```
 def ventas_anio(request):
        ventas = Ventas.objects.all().aggregate(total_payment=Sum('totalventa'))

        return render_to_response('ventasanual.html',{'datos':ventas}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I am not able to use this view.

Comment: I understand Spanish, but I guess people would like it if you could post code in English..

Comment: Thanks I'll take your suggestion for next time ;)

Comment: Well the code is in English, just the variables aren't. That shouldn't be a huge problem.

Comment: @gersande I agree with you...Do you know how to get the total for sold products?

Comment: @dcft unfortunately i'm only just learning python - :c i don't feel confident enough figuring this out - sorry

Comment: @gersande :) ok Good luck learning python it is an awesome and wonderful programming language

Comment: Please update the code with the template tags which you have used. Maybe you have wrong at template. :)

Comment: In templates you should use {{datos.totalventa__sum}} to display it.

Answer (score 0):

ventas = Ventas.objects.aggregate(total_payment=Sum('totalventa'))
I think it should work perfectly if you have data in your respective database.
Output for this will be a dictionary.
Such as {'total_payment': Decimal('xx.xx')} format.

def ventas_anio(request):

```
ventas = Ventas.objects.all().aggregate(total_payment=Sum('totalventa'))
sum_ventas = ventas['total_payment']
return render_to_response('ventasanual.html',{'datos':sum_ventas}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Hello, thanks ..but I got an error "'int' object is not iterable" :(

Comment: Could you please past the error stacktrace so I can help you more in digging the root cause.